# 3 Switch Wall plate to 1 Wall Plate Ceiling Fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, wire

This is for U.S. based electrical in a house built in 2001.

**Current State**

I have a ceiling fan with a light that I am going to replace. With this new fan I want to change the 3 switch configuration down to just one.

I no longer will need two switches (Switch 1 and 2 in image below) as the one switch from the fan's manufacturer will handle all necessary functions.

I also no longer need Switch 3 as I do not want a light switch controlling power to these outlets (but the outlets still need to have power).

[image]

**Future State**

How am I to hook up the wiring so that I get a black and white wire connected to my new fan (it does not have a connection for the red wire), while still having constant power from Cable A (source) to Cable B (outlet), and allowing for Switch 2 to control the power to Cable C/D?

[image]

**My Assumption**

- Leave all Whites connected (A, B, and C)
- Cable C Red to Cable B Red
- Cable A Black and Cable B Black to Switch 2 Port B
- Cable C Black to Switch 2 Port A
- Cable D Black and Cable D Red to Fan Black
- Cable D White to Fan White

Comment: Does the fan switch fit into a standard or decorator-style wallplate, or does it use a weird custom wallplate?

Comment: It fits in a standard Lutron/decora faceplate. I will put blanks in the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Splice all grounds.  Pigtail a ground to the fan-control smart switch.
- Splice all whites
- Splice black A, black B, red B, and a pigtail.
- "LINE" side of your fan-control smart switch to the pigtail.
- "LOAD" side of your fan-control smart switch to Black C.
- Cap Red C.  Do not cut it off! You must cap it and you might want it later.
- Cap Red D.  Ditto.
- Black and white D to fan.

Comment: Yeah -- only problem might be getting a faceplate on the box -- depends on if his funky fan switch fits a regular faceplate, or if it comes with a weirdo faceplate (which will most likely be single gang)